# Angularjs Provider: is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-providers

I am trying to configure my Module with a Provider that should allow a custom configuration. This is my Provider:

```
var module = angular.module('myModule', []);

module.provider('MyModule', function () {


    this.setBaseUrl = function (f) {
        this.BaseUrl = f;
    };

    this.setOnForbidden = function (f) {
        this.onForbidden = f;
    };

    this.setOnTokenExpired = function (f) {
        this.onTokenExpired = f;
    };

    this.setOnUnauthenticated = function (f) {
        this.onUnauthenticated = f;
    };

    this.$get = function () {
        return this;
    };

})
```

And this is my App that uses the Provider:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myModule'])

    .config(function (MyModuleProvider) {
        MyModuleProvider.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8080/");

        MyModuleProvider.setOnForbidden(
            function () {
                console.log("Forbidden - User Function");
            }
        );
        MyModuleProvider.setOnTokenExpired(
            function () {
                console.log("Token Expired - User Function");
            }
        );
        MyModuleProvider.setOnUnauthenticated(
            function () {
                console.log("User Unauthenticated, wrong username or password - User Function");
            }
        );

    })
```

The three functions setOnForbidden, setOnTokenExpired and setOnUnauthenticated are working fine alone, but when I add the `MyModuleProvider.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8080/");` it returns the following error:

Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
TypeError: MyModuleProvider.setBaseUrl is not a function

Why? Is there something wrong in the Provider code?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle, codepen or the like.

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/BpoKYDV6EKJzfpkZ5M0Z?p=preview.

Comment: Yeah https://jsfiddle.net/qnt55y50/

Comment: You all are right, it works. I was debugging it incorrectly.